# How to configure ExtJS 4 Store (proxy and reader) to read metadata

Tags: json, extjs, model, proxy, extjs4

My question is how to get metadata besides totalRecords, in my case it is version, code, searchquery (please look at json).

```
{
"result": {
    "version":"1",
    "code":"200",
    "searchquery": "false",
    "totalRecords": "2",
    "account":[
            {
                "lastname": "Ivanoff", 
                "firstname": "Ivan", 
                "accountId":"1"
            },
            {
                "lastname": "Smirnoff", 
                "firstname": "Ivan", 
                "accountId":"2"
            }
        ]
}
```

}

Here is my model:

```
Ext.define("test.Account", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: 'accountId', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'lastname', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'firstname', type: 'string'}    
    ]
});
```

And store:

```
Ext.define("test.TestStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    model: "test.Account",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: "users.json",  
        reader: {
            type    : 'json',
            root    : 'result.account',
            totalProperty: "result.totalRecords"
        }
    },

    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records, success) {
            console.log("Load: success " + success);     
        }
    }
});
```

Using this store I am able to load records (account) and cannot find any methods to access rest of the fields.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 17):

Here is solution for my problem. I am handling afterRequest event in the Proxy class where I can get response data, parse it and save metadata. This is proxy part of the TestStore class:

So here is proxy part from the TestStore class:

```
proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: "/users.json",  
        reader: {
            type    : 'json',
            root    : 'gip.account',
            totalProperty: "gip.totalRecords",
            searchquery: "searchquery"
        },
        afterRequest: function(req, res) {
            console.log("Ahoy!", req.operation.response);    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use the 'metachange' event of the store.

All the non-extjs specific information can be grouped in JSON in the separate object:

```
{
    "result": {
        "totalRecords": "2",
        "account":[
            {
                "lastname": "Ivanoff", 
                "firstname": "Ivan", 
                "accountId":"1"
            },
            {
                "lastname": "Smirnoff", 
                "firstname": "Ivan", 
                "accountId":"2"
            }
        ]
    },
    "myMetaData": {
        "version":"1",
        "code":"200",
        "searchquery": "false"
    }
}
```

The store is configured as

```
Ext.define("test.TestStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    model: "test.Account",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: "users.json",  
        reader: {
            type    : 'json',
            root    : 'result.account',
            totalProperty: "result.totalRecords",
            metaProperty: 'myMetaData'
        }
    },

    listeners: {
        metachange: function(store, meta) {
            console.log("Version " + meta.version + "Search query " + meta.searchQuery);     
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Ext.data.Proxy` class and more specifically `processResponse()` method. If you need to extract any additional data - you will have to extend standard class and change that method.

Comment: i checked proxy class. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy - not finding `processResponse()` method there. i am finding one in Ext.form.action.Action. Can you make this answer bit more clear.

Comment: check `Ext.data.proxy.Server` class in 4.0.7 (I think OP has ExtJs4 not 4.1 - but they should be relatively similar)

Comment: thank you for the tip with processResponse method but I am working with 4.1 version and decided not to touch framework files.

However I found another solution for my problem. Proxy class has afterRequest event, handling this event I can get response data with all metadata field.