# Display different views of the same model with extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I try to use ExtJS to display different views of the same model (each view to display a subset of the model).

I have a nested model that loads the following xml:

```
<results>
  <hitcount>1234</hitcount>
  <recommended>
     <title>foo</title>
  </recommended>
  <result>
    <title>title1</title>  
    <author>author1</author>  
  </result>
  <result>
    <title>title2</title>  
    <author>author2</author>  
  </result>
</results>
```

I'd like to have different widgets that each display part of this model (one list to display 'result', another to display 'recommended', another widget to display the hitcount).

What I don't know is how to declare the store on each widget to target only a subset of the full model.

Sounds like a basic approach, but I failed to find an example of this (I found many examples of nested structures, but not one with a store scoped on a subset of the model).

See below some attempt where I try to get only the result part.

```
Ext.define("MySenchaApp.model.ResultModel", {
    extend:"Ext.data.Model",

    config:{
        associations: [
            {
                type:'hasMany',
                model:'MySenchaApp.model.Result',
                name:'results',
                associationKey:'result'
            }
        ],


        proxy:{

            type:"ajax",
            url:'Results.xml',

            reader:{
                type:'xml',
                rootProperty:'results'
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.define("MySenchaApp.model.Result", {
    extend:"Ext.data.Model",

    config:{
        fields:['title', 'author'],
        belongsTo: 'MySenchaApp.model.ResultModel'
    }
});

Ext.define('MySenchaApp.view.Results', {
    extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype:'blog',


    config:{
        title:'Results',
        items: [
            {
                xtype:'list',
                itemTpl:'<b>{title}</b> - by <i>{author}</i>',

                store:{
                    autoLoad:true,
                    model:'MySenchaApp.model.Result' // ??
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: If I am understanding right, you don't have to target a subset of the model. You can have a model with 100 fields but only use 3 of them in one of the widgets. Just because it is in the model doesn't mean it has to be used

Comment: how would the List guess that I want to display result instead of 'recommended' for example ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide an association stores as a config because these are never singletons.

### Explanation

Consider the following example:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',   type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ],
    hasMany: {model: 'Product', name: 'products'}
});
```

Now it makes complete sense that some people would like to have a store of users, each with its own products association. So if `aUser1` and `aUser2` are two user records stored in the user store, it is completely legit to do something like this:

```
aUser1.products().add( ... );
aUser2.products().add( ... );
```

The point is that with associations, there's not such thing as a singleton store - there is a store for each record.

Your XML suggest that there can't be more than 1 `results`, in which case you shouldn't really use associations. You should do something along these lines:

```
Ext.define("MySenchaApp.model.Results", {
    extend:"Ext.data.Model",

    fields:['title', 'author'],

    proxy:{

        type:"ajax",
        url:'Results.xml',

        reader:{
            type:'xml',
            rootProperty:'results'
        }
    }

});
```

And provide the following XML:

```
<metadata>
    <hitcount>1234</hitcount>
    <recommended>
        <title>foo</title>
    </recommended>
</metadata>
<results>
    <result>
        <title>title1</title>  
        <author>author1</author>  
    </result>
    <result>
        <title>title2</title>  
        <author>author2</author>  
    </result>
</results>
```

Use the proxy's `metachange` event to inspect hitcount and recommended.

Comment: Looks like this will answer my immediate need thanks, I found here an example of what you describe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000819/how-to-configure-extjs-4-store-proxy-and-reader-to-read-metadata

Comment: I wonder though how you would deal with multiple lists (example: list of results with a list of facets, and a list for each of them).

Comment: In this case you will be looking into hasMany associations, and then my original point stands: there is no singleton store you can give to your widgets - you'll have to do this programmatically (by saying to the widget "this is your store now", so in the case of a grid it would be via `reconfigure`).